# Receiving strings larger than 64 bytes using Web USB API

Tags: javascript, usb, webusb

I am working on a project involving web usb apit where I need to recieve a JSON object that is larger than 64 bytes, at the moment I am using a buffer and a delimiter to receive the whole object, is there an easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the maximum packet size for your endpoint is 64 bytes and that it is a bulk endpoint. When submitting a transfer request you can specify a size larger than the maximum packet size. In this case data will be read from the device across multiple packets until either the requested size is reached or the host receives a zero-length packet.

That said I recommend that, while you can and should improve efficiency by specifying a larger transfer size, unless there is a maximum size for this JSON blob you should also continue to also use a delimiter to determine when it has been fully received.